# MVC System.InvalidOperationException: but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[smoethng]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Selam,

```
public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            var model = new HomeViewModel();
            using (var context = new BannerEntities())
            {
                model.FotoList = context.Fotos.ToList();
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

And the view is

```
@model IEnumerable<Banner.Models.HomeViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>
```

I am taking the  error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Banner.Models.HomeViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Banner.Models.HomeViewModel]'.
Is there any idea why is that problem occure?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a single instance of `Banner.Models.HomeViewModel`, but your view is expecting an `IEnumerable` collection of `Banner.Models.HomeViewModel`.

Change your view to look like this and it should work:

```
@model Banner.Models.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>
```